# Oracle SQL Header and detail with different number of output columns

Tags: sql, oracle, header

I need to output a file using ORACLE sql in following format

```
HEADR,xx,20170130145001
DTROW,1357924680135,9876543210
DTROW,2468013579246,1234567890
TRAIL,3
```

I have created the following code. Which nearly works, but problem is Trailer record only has two fields. To make union work i have added null in field3. But,
this means output looks like this when export. Header and detail have 3 fields, trailer only has 2.

When run query get following

```
FIELD1  FIELD2         FIELD3 
HEADR   XX             20181108145437
DTROW   1357924680135  9876543210
DTROW   2468013579246  1234567890
TRAIL   3              null
```

When export to a csv file get following

```
HEADR,XX,20181108092508
DTROW,1357924680135,9876543210
DTROW,2468013579246,1234567890
TRAIL,3,      <<===== I don't want to have , after 2
```

This is code i used:

```
WITH     main_query     AS
(
     SELECT 'DTROW'                               AS field1
     ,       ACCT                                 AS field2
     ,       ID                                   AS field3
     ,       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ACCT)   AS r_num
     FROM       MYTABLE 
)
,     union_data     AS
(
     -- Header line
         SELECT  'HEADR'                                AS field1
     ,           'XX'                                   AS field2
     ,           TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')   AS field3
     ,           0                                      AS r_num
     FROM     dual
           --
     UNION ALL
            --
     -- Main query
     SELECT     *
     FROM     main_query
          --
     UNION ALL
            --
     -- Trailer line

     SELECT 'TRAIL'                   AS field1
     ,       TO_CHAR(COUNT(*) + 1 )   AS field2
     ,       NULL                     AS field3
     ,       NULL                     AS r_num
     FROM     main_query
)
SELECT       field1
,            field2
,            field3
FROM       union_data
ORDER BY  r_num          NULLS LAST
;
```

How do i get round this problem. The exported csv file will have , at end
of the trailer record because field 3 is null.

I don't want the the comma since the trailer record should only have 2 fields.
So when exported to csv should look like this.

```
 TRAIL,3
```

not like this

```
 TRAIL,3,
```

The sql code will run in Bi Publisher and output a csv file. So I can't edit the file afterwards.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the hanging comma? For sure you can't fix it in SQL

Comment: Use another query to output the last row or trim it using  unix utilities `sed/tr`

Comment: Can't use sed or any editor.  The sql will run and an output will be exported automatically, so have no control once sql's run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem has nothing to do with SQL. Your query is returning three columns and BI Publisher is converting those to a CSV, and this "trailing comma" is happening because of a NULL value in the third column. Unless BI Publisher has a way to prevent this (and I doubt it does, because that would completely screw up a CSV), the only thing I can think of is to build the CSV as a single column yourself:

```
[...]
SELECT field1 || ',' || field2 ||
       CASE WHEN field3 IS NOT NULL THEN
           ',' || TO_CHAR( field3 ) END NULL END AS all_fields
  FROM union_data
ORDER BY r_num NULLS LAST
```

This ignores the case where field2 and field3 are both null.

Comment: Thanks this worked just had to remove the END NULL, so just had END as all_fields rather than END NULL   END AS all_fields, which gave a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question.  You have sample results with a single column, but your result set has three columns.  Your query is also quite hard to follow (I have to scroll both horizontally and vertically).

If you want to remove the final comma in an Oracle query, then use `trim()`:

```
trim(trailing ',' from xxx)
```

Comment: Hi, i have updated, hopefully is a bit clearer. I can't use trim because the comma only appears on the exported file which is generated automatically so have no control after the sql has run. Was hoping to have a way of removing field3 from the trailer record, added it so UNION had identical number of fields, without which it gave an error.